# Make field in Access report (in)visible based off another field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to have a text box show/not show based off the value in another field on an Access report and I can't figure out if my VBA is wrong of if I'm using the wrong trigger.

I can't get this to trigger:

```
 Private Sub Report_Load()
    If Me.Bill = 64 Then
       Me.Code64.Visible = True
    Else
       Me.Code64.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

I've tried adding ".value" after "Bill" and putting quotes around "64"

I can't for the life of me figure out how to get it to trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code would have to be in Format event of section that contains the control. Event only runs for direct to printer or PrintPreview, not ReportView.

Alternatively, could just have expression in textbox and eliminate VBA.

`=IIf([Bill] = 64, Null, [Cod64])`